# Need a bit of assistance

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio, android-sqlite

I need help with my app, I created an app but it runs slowly, i guess because of the background and the images, now i read somwhere i should use threads and a loading screen until all app images are loaded so it runs faster. I dont know how to use threads, could you elp me or at least send me somewhere I can learn how to do it. One more thing i get an error whne i am using Activity extends fragment at loading sql something at getappid or something like that. is there an easy way to fix it? This app is made for android 4.0 - android L

My application can be found at the link below:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/22kchus06l2lf0u/app-release.apk
If you need more info like main xml and main java code i can paste it here...

Thanks anyway !

Comment: android 4.0 is ICS and not L. And for god's sake, READ THIS and then edit your question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Droidman: I think he meant that it's made to work with the versions ranging from ICS (4.0) to L. :-)

Comment: yep you are right it is from 4.0 to L XD

Comment: @ninetwozero this would do a little bit more sense but that's generally not a good idea since L is bugged as hell right now.
@Peky5 please follow the link I posted. In general: briefly describe what you are trying to achieve, post your code, what errors are you getting, post your LogCat output, what have you tried and then you'll get help. Linking an `apk`(lolwhat?) is definitely not the way to ask questions here on SO

Comment: You migh find CREATING INDEXES a real accelerator. Google for that you'll easily find how to.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

A very basic example of a `Thread`:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(
    public void run(){
        // Do stuff here
    }
).start();
```

Everything inside the body of run() will be executed separately from the UI thread.

Comment: "putting" an `AsyncTask` inside the `run()` method of a `Thread`? Can you explain how it does make any sense?

Comment: Maybe better to say "perform operations that you want to be on the new thread here"

Comment: Ok, and how should i make the async task. Because i only need the background to load there. so it can be loaded faster. backgrounds are located in my drawable maps, and how can i make threads cooperate with time lets say 5 seconds? Sorry if i am anoying :D